# How to display non-English characters as label in Geopandas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, geopandas, annotate

I have a shapefile in polygon type. In table of this shapefile there is a column with `NAME` name. This column characters are in `Farsi` font, non-English. I want to read this file with `Geopandas` in `jupyter` and then display name of each polygon label based on the `NAME` column. I use the below code. It can display the map plot but the labels show as `????` character. Is there any idea to solve it?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cities = gpd.read_file(r'/Maps/my_polygon.shp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5)) 
cities.plot(color='black', edgecolor='k',linewidth = 1,ax=ax)
cities.geometry.boundary.plot(color=None, edgecolor='k',linewidth = 1,ax=ax)

# Labeling name of cities with field of 'NAME'
cities.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(x.NAME, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center'),axis=1);
```

Comment: I strongly suspect this is down to the encoding of file. If you have a look at the dataframe after import, are the names parsed correctly? If not, try passing the `encoding` parameter with the appropriate value to `gpd.read_file()` and see if it works. E.g.: `cities = gpd.read_file(r'/Maps/my_polygon.shp', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Hi @bexi, I tried your suggestion and did not work.

Comment: hi @nickam, it might also be another encoding. Does the shapefile come with a .cpg file (`'/Maps/my_polygon.cpg'` in your case)? This may contain information about the encoding of the shapefile.